# How To get The controller data To view

Tags: sapui5

I have a requirement from where I am modifying The model data and keeping in controller variable in JSON format .  Now i need to bind that in Table .
Could you please help me .

I have searched everywhere . I didn't get the exact answer.

```
for (var i = 0; i < agrdata.length; i++) {
            if (agrdata[i].vendno === this.selectedven) {
                //var array = {"vendno": agrdata[i].vendno};
                var percent = agrdata[i].revenue / 999 * 100;
                This.FilterAgr.push({
                    vendno: agrdata[i].vendno,
                    agrno: agrdata[i].agrno,
                    revenue: agrdata[i].revenue,
                    percent: percent.toFixed(2)
                });
            }
        }
```

I want to display FilterAGr in My VIew Table . How to bind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your JSON model in manifest:

```
"models": {
    "jsonModel": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel"
    }
},
```

Put data in your JSON model in your controller:

```
var oLocalModel = this.getModel("jsonModel");
var aFilterAgr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < agrdata.length; i++) {
  if (agrdata[i].vendno === this.selectedven) {
    var percent = agrdata[i].revenue / 999 * 100;

    aFilterAgr.push({
      vendno: agrdata[i].vendno,
      agrno: agrdata[i].agrno,
      revenue: agrdata[i].revenue,
      percent: percent.toFixed(2)
    });        
  }
}

oLocalModel.setProperty("/TableData", aFilterAgr); //Put table data in your JSON model
```

Bind JSON model to your table in your XML view:

```
<Table items="{jsonModel>/TableData}">
```

[More information about JSON models](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/06/02/how-to-load-a-json-model-from-manifest-file-and-send-json-object-as-a-parameter-through-routing-and-navigation/)